# Is there a way of traversing from string to int array and vice versa

Tags: java, arrays, string

In Java, given the array

```
int a[] = {1,2,3}
```

I can do `Arrays.toString(a)` to get

```
"[1,2,3]"
```

Is there an equally convenient way to return this String back to its antecedent array?
Or must I go through the whole `split`, for-loop, `parseInt` stuff?

**UPDATE**

Thanks everyone for all the thoughts. I rolled out my own function as

```
String src[] = data.split("\\D+");//data is intArrayAsString: [1,2,3]
int[] nums = new int[src.length - 1];
int ndx = 0;
for (String s : src) {
  try {
    nums[ndx] = Integer.parseInt(s);
    ndx++;
  } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
  }
}
return nums;
```

Note: the word traverse seems to have thrown a few people off. By "traversing" I meant the ability to move back and forth from the string to the int array.

Comment: For traversing the list you can use listIterator `ListIterator<Integer> iterator = Arrays.asList(a);` or i don't tested  `new StringBuilder(Arrays.toString(a)).reverse().toString();` --> but you'll have `]3,2,1[`

Comment: Use `Integer`(int wrapper) instead of `int`, so it has `toString()` method, and may help you.

Comment: Is JSON an option? ;-)

Comment: One could in theory parse the string as JSON and obtain a Map of Integer objects.  Not exactly reversing things.

Comment: (It should be noted that if the intent is to use this data for something like sending/receiving over the network then JSON is the preferred format.  A JSON encoder will produce a string essentially identical to `toString` for an array of `int`, and will also seamlessly handle other more complex data layouts.  And decoding comes as a part of the package.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know, no.

But it's easy to do using [`Split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29).

I just did this, if you don't understand how to do it:

```
int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4};
String toString = Arrays.toString(arr);

System.out.println(toString);

// we know it starts with [ and ] so we skip it
String[] items = toString.substring(1, toString.length() - 1).split(",");
int[] arr2 = new int[items.length];
for (int i = 0; i < items.length; ++i)
{
    arr2[i] = Integer.parseInt(items[i].trim()); // .trim() because it adds the space and parseInt don't like spaces
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr2));
```

(free to improve it, it's just a draft)

Comment: `StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead.`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any existing method, so I wrote you my own version:

```
import java.util.Arrays;


public class ArrayToString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[] = {1,2,3};
        String serialized = Arrays.toString(a);
        System.out.println(serialized);

        int[] b = stringToIntArray(serialized);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
    }

    private static int[] stringToIntArray(String serialized) {

        // remove '[' and ']'
        String raw = serialized.replaceAll("^\\[(.*)\\]$", "$1");

        // split by separators
        String[] splitStrings = raw.split(", ");

        // create new int array
        int[] b = new int[splitStrings.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < splitStrings.length; i++) {
            String splitString = splitStrings[i];

            // parse each text individually
            b[i] = Integer.parseInt(splitString);
        }
        return b;
    }

}
```